# Preprocessing landsat 8 images in R

Tags: r, landsat-8

I'm preprocessing landsat 8 images in R  using the packages 'satellite' and 'landsat'. I tried to work with a "satellite object" derived from a stack of all my bands, but when applying the correction commands (e.g. convDN2RU)
the satellite object is not recognized.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Might be helpful to include a code snippet of where you think it's failing.

Answer (score 1):

Probably more of a comment, but can't post comments yet, so hope this is helpful.  One thing I'd recommend is trying this in the new R package [RStoolbox](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RStoolbox/).  It has functions for preprocessing that pull info straight out of the metadata file. (see 'radCor').  I'd say to try that, and if it doesn't work, post back with the actual error message details and such.